# Во время сборки приложения ошибка Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'

Tags: android

Пытаюсь собрать release версию приложения и получить apk. в ответ получаю сообщение

```
 Generate Signed APK
    Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view.
```

в логах пишет вот такое

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
>   Job failed, see logs for details

ну и ссылается на библиотеки для работы с сетью

```
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.ConnectionReuseStrategy
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor
Warning:there were 74 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:there were 127 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

**Event Log**

```
13:43:52 Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) and 169 warning(s) in 13s 295ms
13:43:52 Build APK: Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view.
```

Comment: `Messages` - это не ваша `View`. Это вкладка в Android Studio. Не помню где она именно, но она есть

Comment: И что с ней можно сделать дабы скомпилировать нормально apk файл?

Comment: Ну.. Наверное почитать логи? А если не разберетесь - дополните им вопрос.

Comment: @СергейГрушин обновил и добавил логи, ничего не понял...гугл тоже молчит, такое чувство что такое случается крайне редко

Comment: Гугл вроде [не молчит](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052437/proguard-warning-library-class-android-webkit-webview-depends-on-program-class-a), [ещё](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535346/android-proguard-error-in-android-studio). [И вот неплохой](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381577/proguard-giving-the-following-error-while-exporting-the-application)

Comment: stackoverflow-то не молчит, но ignore warnings - это не объяснение причины этой багофичи, @vp_arth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас включен proguard для релизной сборки. Скорее всего у вас в некорректно настроен файл proguard.pro.

[Вот тут про proguard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html)

[Вот тут коллекция правил под разные популярные библиотеки](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/tree/master/libraries)

В вашем случае, возможно, поможет такой набор:

```
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
```

Comment: Странно, раньше этой проблемы не возникало. А когда пытаюсь отключить proguard...android studio ругается

Answer (score 1):

```
release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    signingConfig signingConfigs.config
}
```

В фале build.gradle изменил `minifyEnabled true` на `minifyEnabled false` и получилось.